# jQuery append element using parent attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to user jQuery to, for each element using the class `button-0`, add a new child element with the class `button-0-text`, and the text equal to the `data-text` attribute of the original `button-0` element. I tried this...

HTML:

```
<div class="flex fs-0 button-0" data-text="Enhance"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(".button-0").append($("<div></div>").addClass("button-0-text").text($(this).parent().attr("data-text")));
```

...but it's not working. Is this even the proper way to do it? Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you ^.^

Answer (score 2):

Try this way:

```js
$('.button-0').each(function() {
  $(this).append('<div class="button-0-text">' +$(this).data('text')+ '</div>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="flex fs-0 button-0" data-text="Enhance1"></div>
<div class="flex fs-0 button-0" data-text="Enhance2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
var buttons = $('.button-0');
buttons.each(function(i, elem){
  var child = $('<div/>', {'class': 'button-0-text'});
  child.text($(this).data('text'));
  child.appendTo(this);
});
```